# Could not create the java virtual machine in Opentaps

Tags: installation, crm, opentaps

I am installing opensource of Opentaps by this instruction visit http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/General_Installation_of_Opentaps

But I get an error:

> Could not create the java virtual machine.

This is what I have done:

1. Open cmd and go to directory c:\opentaps
2. `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04`
3. Use command `startofbiz.bat`

Finally I get the errors:

> Could not create the Java Virtual Machine
>
> A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Solution 2 failes. When I change something in "startofbiz.bat' file by [this instruction](http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/Recommended_Memory_Settings)
I get the same issue like above.

Solution 3 fails. I have also changed the memory settings to `-Xms256M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M`. Now I get outofmemory exception in console.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

We have couple of solutions for the above Problem

Solution 1: You can re-install the all components. ie it means you have install the entire s/w. for the Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Solution 2: that maximum heap size varies based upon machine architecture e.g. 32 bit or 64 bit, JVM bit size e.g. 32 bit JVM or 64 bit JVM and operating system.

In 32 bit machine though theoretical limit of maximum heap size is 4GB, it varies on operating system to operating system e.g. on 32 bit windows XP maximum heap size limits upto 1.5G due to various reason while on 64 bit Solaris machine even with 32 bit JVM you can afford around 3.5GB. So when you run following java command in 32 bit Windows XP machine

Solution 3: One more worth noting syntax error while providing heap space is space between numeric literal and unit, as shown in below example: (1)Correct: ~/java java -Xmx1500 M and (2)In-correct: ~/java java -Xmx1500MB and (3)In-Correct: ~/java java -Xmx 1400M

Regards, Ravindra Seelam